# Customize ordered lists increments

Tags: html

How can i display custom ordered list ? Is it possible to get below output

> Tour 1: Hello
>
> Tour 2: Whats up ?
>
> Tour 3: Bye
>
> Tour 4: Test Tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element to do this effect, but I'm not sure as far as the colon goes:

```
<ol class="tour">
    <li>First thing's first</li>
    <li>Second's the best</li>
    <li>Why not third?, Because I though it was the best.</li>
    <li>How about fourth?</li>
</ol>
```

And the CSS (margins would need to be tweaked to your liking - although you could probably use positioning to achieve the same thing):

```
ol.tour li:before {
    content:"Tour";
    margin-left:-60px; 
    margin-right:30px;
}
ol.tour{
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4s8fo2q/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) and [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) to prepend a word to an increment.  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mL4fv7xp/5/)

**HTML**

```
<ol>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Whats Up</li>
    <li>Bye</li>
    <li>How Are You</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol {
  counter-reset: tour;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: tour;
  content: "Tour " counter(tour) ": ";  
}
```

**Output**

> Tour 1: Hello
>
> Tour 2: Whats up ?
>
> Tour 3: Bye
>
> Tour 4: Test Tour

**Explanation**

- Using [counter-reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) sets the `<ol>` counter to your counter `tour`
- Every `<li>` increments `tour` with [counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment)
- Set the `content` of the pseudo element `:before` to `"Tour " +  counter value + ": "`

Comment: Hi @brain ,thank you for posting it works perfect but when a particular <li> has too much content the text start from Tour 3 please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z6994z4j/)

Comment: Im glad you're happy with the answer :) You can fix that like so: http://jsfiddle.net/z6994z4j/1/

Comment: white-space to nowrap won't work as my div got width the content will go outside my div :( @brain

Comment: @brain you have updated the question , Earlier I have wrote 3rd `<li>` content purposely `Tour 3: Bye ` and `Some data` on next line giving spacing. thank you writing

Comment: So you don't want the text to go on a new line correct? or no? You want to avoid adding extra content between tour 3 and 4?

Comment: Im assuming yes, that is what white-space: nowrap is for.. the only other available solution, other than reducing your word count, is the `overflow` property which is for when things 'overflow', you need to add a scroll bar if width of content exceeds width of wrapper IE overflow: auto. http://jsfiddle.net/2uejmf0w/2/

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch that :) I thought it was a typo

Comment: That doesn't have a new line.. nor does it solve a new line issue. Please be clear about what you are asking...

Comment: Here is the "expected output" you just linked to, http://jsfiddle.net/2uejmf0w/3/ it doesn't work. I have given you the solution, use no wrap to keep on one line and overflow auto to account for the length of the sentence http://jsfiddle.net/2uejmf0w/2/ or reduce the length of the sentence. . Please mark as correct and have a nice day.

Comment: @brain sorry if i wasn't unable to explain it properly. But if you check the 3rd `<li>` how data been shown up [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zwn5dxye/)